# Print same word found in certain columns while are blank fields below successively in UNIX

Tags: bash, unix, awk

This is a shorten tabulated input.tsv

```
rs928302        YES     TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_001256317.1  NP_001243246.1
                                rf      G       V       53      NM_024022.2     NP_076927.1
                                rf      G       V       53      NM_032405.1     NP_115781.1
rs1046210       YES     BACE2   rf      C       D       364     NM_012105.4     NP_036237.2
                                rf      C       D       364     NM_138992.2     NP_620477.1
                                rf      C       D       269     XM_017028314.1  XP_016883803.1
rs1064579       YES     IFNGR2  rf      T       V       272     NM_001329128.1  NP_001316057.1
                                rf      T       V       253     NM_005534.3     NP_005525.2
                                rf      T       V       272     XM_005260969.2  XP_005261026.1
                                rf      T       V       278     XM_011529553.1  XP_011527855.1
                                rf      T       V       255     XM_011529554.2  XP_011527856.1
```

And I would like to print in blank fields the same word found on the top and apply to the first, second and third columns until the end of file. When appear a different word the printing below should be this new word and so on. So the output should be:

```
rs928302        YES     TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_001256317.1  NP_001243246.1
rs928302        YES     TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_024022.2     NP_076927.1
rs928302        YES     TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_032405.1     NP_115781.1
rs1046210       YES     BACE2   rf      C       D       364     NM_012105.4     NP_036237.2
rs1046210       YES     BACE2   rf      C       D       364     NM_138992.2     NP_620477.1
rs1046210       YES     BACE2   rf      C       D       269     XM_017028314.1  XP_016883803.1
rs1064579       YES     IFNGR2  rf      T       V       272     NM_001329128.1  NP_001316057.1
rs1064579       YES     IFNGR2  rf      T       V       253     NM_005534.3     NP_005525.2
rs1064579       YES     IFNGR2  rf      T       V       272     XM_005260969.2  XP_005261026.1
rs1064579       YES     IFNGR2  rf      T       V       278     XM_011529553.1  XP_011527855.1
rs1064579       YES     IFNGR2  rf      T       V       255     XM_011529554.2  XP_011527856.1
```

How can do it in Unix environment? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) {
        if ($i == "") {
            $i = p[i]
        }
        else {
            p[i] = $i
        }
    }
    print
}
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk 'NF==9{ f1=$1; f2=$2; f3=$3 }
     NF==6{ sub(/^[[:space:]]+/,"",$0); 
     $0=f1 OFS f2 OFS f3 OFS $0 }1' OFS='\t' file
```

The output:

```
rs928302    YES TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_001256317.1  NP_001243246.1
rs928302    YES TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_024022.2     NP_076927.1
rs928302    YES TMPRSS3 rf      G       V       53      NM_032405.1     NP_115781.1
rs1046210   YES BACE2   rf      C       D       364     NM_012105.4     NP_036237.2
rs1046210   YES BACE2   rf      C       D       364     NM_138992.2     NP_620477.1
rs1046210   YES BACE2   rf      C       D       269     XM_017028314.1  XP_016883803.1
rs1064579   YES IFNGR2  rf      T       V       272     NM_001329128.1  NP_001316057.1
rs1064579   YES IFNGR2  rf      T       V       253     NM_005534.3     NP_005525.2
rs1064579   YES IFNGR2  rf      T       V       272     XM_005260969.2  XP_005261026.1
rs1064579   YES IFNGR2  rf      T       V       278     XM_011529553.1  XP_011527855.1
rs1064579   YES IFNGR2  rf      T       V       255     XM_011529554.2  XP_011527856.1
```